# Design Pattern in real world

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am learning design pattern from Head first book and I understood most of them. But when I try to apply in real world, it becomes more difficult. In every example, it has created lot of sub classes. But do we really create so much classes in real time projects?

E.g. Consider an example of Bank Account
Approach 1:

```
    Account {

    String name;
    double balance;
    operation1() {
    }
}


SavingAccount extends Account {
    // some extra fields and methods related to saving account 
    operation1() {
    }

}

CurrentAccount extends Account {
    // Some extra fields and methods related to current account.
    operation1() {
    }

}
```

When I map these classes with database, using Hibernate using one of the inheritance strategy, e.g. table per sub class, I will end up with three tables. Account, Saving_account and Current_account.
Advantage: I can call operation1() depending on the type of object using polymorphism.

Disadvantage: more tables and classes. If project is more complex and big, It will end up with thousands of classes.

Approach 2:

```
    Account {
    string name;
    double balance;
    string type;
    operation1() {
    }
}
```

I need only 1 table for this approach called Account. And "type" field will identify the type of the account.

Advantage: Only 1 table and class.
Disadvantage: I will lose Object oriented world and every place I have to put the condition as below.

```
    if (type == saving) {
    // do this;
} else if (type == current) {
    // do that;
}
```

As per theory, approach 1 is correct and best. But currently in my project, approach 2 is used. My project is not banking. I took it as an example for the simplicity.

I know this is very basic question. But due to my current project implementation, I could not stop myself asking this question.

EDIT: maintainability of approach 1 is more better than approach 2.

Comment: What design pattern are you describing?

Comment: I am just talking about general object oriented design of classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design patterns like inheritance are difficult to describe in terms of their importance, because it takes a very large project to realize the power of it. Usually examples end up with stuff like:

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends B {
}

class D extends A {
}
```

And then you get a lot of not so real life questions like which method `foo()` really refers to when it's implemented four separate times.

The motivation for using inheritance is to group similar types of things together in a class. A basic example is if you want to have a bunch of different objects all in a list together. This isn't possible if they're all different types, but if they're in an inheritance hierarchy, you can group them all together.

For your example, you can put every `Account` object into a single list, no matter which subclass the objects are really in.

```
List<Account> list = new ArrayList<Account> ();
list.add(new Account());
list.add(new SavingsAccount());
list.add(new CurrentAccount());
```

Say you want to process every thing in that list. If you have one common method, you can use polymorphism to make each `Account` do its own specific action:

```
for(Account a : list) {
   a.operation1();
}
```

Much simpler than having a separate list for each type of object, no? And then if you want to make more types of accounts, if you extend the base `Account` class, you don't have to add new lists and new loops to your code. Everything can remain as is.

Using inheritance also helps to use code that other people have written. If you want to add something to a class that someone else has written, you can include it in a package and then extend it with one of your own classes. That way you don't have to do a lot of copy and pasting and navigating through the other class's source code. You also can extend another class even if you only have its `.class` file, rather than the source code in a `.java` file.

So the power of inheritance depends on how you use it. In a small example, it doesn't really make sense. But the bigger the project, the more it makes sense.

Comment: Yes my project is very complex and bigger. So do you recommend to use approach 1 in that case right?

Comment: Yes, although of course it will depend on the specific structure of your project. In general, the bigger and the more complex the project, the more sense it makes to make use of inheritance. As with any aspect of design, I'd recommend outlining your project using several design patterns, and then choose the one that makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are valid as you just mentioned and the pros and cons you explained are also valid.

But for example you if you are Giving this Accounting package (compiled jar) as a library to be extended by other people, the approach 1 is ideal because;

1. You don't need to modify any source code of `Account`, just extend it and then implement your own version. Ex:- `FixedDepositAccount`
2. Won't break your `Account` code.
3. No need of Testing again for `Account.operation1()`

But if you are willing to share the source code and willing to do above mentioned steps then it is best to use method 2.

Comment: Maintainability of code is an issue with approach 2 right?

Answer (score 0):

In Java we can have `String type;` (not `string type;`), but even better would be an [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) type (that way we could have add a Money Market Account or a Platinum Preferred Savings Account, possibly without re-implementing the caller code). Something like,

```
 enum AccountType {
    CHECKING(0.005), SAVINGS(0.01), MMA(0.02);
    final double rate;

    private AccountType(double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
    public double getRate() {
        return this.rate;
    }
}
```

And with an `AccountType` you can safely use `==` for equality, while doing `if (type == saving) {` with a `String` is asking for trouble. That is

```
if (type == AccountType.CHECKING) {
} else if (type == AccountType.SAVINGS) {
```

will function as you would expect. Finally, it would be better to try and avoid the `if` chains and instead encapsulate whatever you plan to do with the account type into the enum itself when you can. For example,

```
Account acct = getAccount(accountNumber);
if (acct != null && acct.isValid()) {
  acct.balance += acct.balance * type.getRate();
}
```

Comment: The code I mentioned is just pseudo code. It is not the exact code. So do you suggest approach 2?

Comment: @javafan Please update your question with real code, I can only answer based on what you have posted.

Comment: I am just trying to understand how to design classes and corresponding tables in complex scenarios with this bank account example. I do not have any specific code.